# Best practice: How to call Objective-C code from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I've been looking for a way to call Objective-C code from some JavaScript in my *UIWebView*. A lot of topics has been created about this, and some of them are recommending the procedure done in the blog post [*UIWebView Secrets - Part3 - How to Properly Call ObjectiveC From Javascript*](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/), where *UIWebViewDelegate* methods are hacked to call native Objective-C code from. Is this still the best way to do this? It seems that [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) has a way to do this, but I cannot find out how to. But if their procedure is equal to this, I cannot see why I should include their library just to do this.

Which procedure is currently best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using the [NativeBridge](https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge) plugin recommended in [the blog post](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/).

Comment: Does `windowScriptObject` not work with iOS like it does with OSX? I'm using that at least with NSWebView on OSX, rather than UIWebView.

Comment: Also, for readers of this answer, and sort of slightly related, I noticed that IFRAMEs inside the NSWebView component can call the ObjC injected bridge in the DOM by calling `window.parent.objc.classMethod()` where `objc` might be what you wanted `windowScriptingObject` to call your object, and `classMethod()` is any class method you wanted to call.

Answer (score 1):

Without any external framework we can do that.To achieve this like phone we have to use webView.
**For example, If you need to call an objective c function when a button is clicked in the webview.When the onclick of your button in the html page calls a javascript, just add an iFrame which will include the function name of the objective C function.**

eg:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "js-frame:" + functionName + ":" + callbackId);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null
```

;

**This iFrame can be accesed in your webView Delegate implemented in your ParentView of the webView, like-**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];




    if ([requestString hasPrefix:@"js-frame:"]) {

        NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        NSString *function = (NSString*)[components objectAtIndex:1];
        int callbackId = [((NSString*)[components objectAtIndex:2]) intValue];

                                  stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        ;

        [self handleCall:function callbackId:callbackId];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**The handleCall will have to handle the invoking of your intended method having name "function"**

Answer (score 0):

There is no (public) API to do this other than using a custom URL scheme inside your JS code to invoke javascript.

Let's say you load the URL `myproto://invokeMethodA` in your JS code like so

```
window.location.href = "myproto://invokeMethodA";
```

you can intercept that load in `UIWebView`s delegate method

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

and do your stuff. Make sure you return `NO` to not actually perform the the request.